# How can I push my local website on visual studio code to a webapp I deployed on Azure

Tags: html, css, azure, web-applications, visual-studio-code

I developed a local website on vs code using basic html and CSS. I then deployed an Azure web app. I want to push the local website to the Azure web app

I watched videos on youtube but the sets didn't work. I have tried using Azuredevops as well

Comment: If Code doesn't offer an option to do that, there are many other deployment options. Perhaps the simplest option is to go to `https://yourwebapp.scm.azurewebsites.net` Console and drag and drop your files to the wwwroot folder. Then as long as there is an index.html file all should work. You can also use a local git repo in the Web app and push new versions to it with git.

Comment: There is a [Azure App Service for Visual Studio Code extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-azuretools.vscode-azureappservice) to create, manage, and deploy Web Apps on the Azure .

Comment: I think there is *now* an extension that makes this easy if your target is Azure:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/publish-to-azure-webapp-using-vscode?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio Code does not have an integrated build system (Web Publish) like Visual Studio does. But it does have command line task running and Git built in.

- Use a task runner to kick off your build/publish from the command palette (ctrl+p). Grunt is available. This requires that you manually script it out, but once that is done, it is easy to kick off the task from that point.

Compatible task runner details: https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/tasks

- Another option is to create a CI/CD pipeline using your source control like Git or Azure Devops to execute your build and release task.

You can use MSBuild task from visual studio code for deploying the website:

```
msbuild <Project or Solution Path> /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=<Publish Profile Name>
```

You can point to a solution, this will publish ALL the projects that includes a valid Publish Profile

```
msbuild <FullPath>\MySolution.sln /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=Test
```

Hope it helps.